# C++ programming and eventually Mobile

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I want to build eventually fully native android C++ applications that can be transferred to iOS, where should I start

First off to make answering this question easier, I would consider my self almost an intermediate C++ programmer I have not gotten off the command line programs yet, but I understand how Vectors, arrays, pointers, OOP, and the basics I am not at 100% yet, which is why I am asking this question.

I have written a few android applications with the sdk in java but my boss now wants iOS applications and he doesn't want to buy me a mac, (that is why I'm sticking to fully native android in c++ rather than going to iOS)

1) First I am confused on what book to buy that will get my from the beginning level C++ programming to the next step,... should I focus on learning windows API's if so what books and tutorials should I get because I am tired of buying kindle books that are either way to advanced or have things I already understand (I can't find one in the middle to challenge me to move on with my c++)  So, What do you guys suggest should I go straight into learning android in c++ or should I try and go somewhere else and get even better at C++ first

2) if I should go into android, or the ndk, is there any good books that actually support android ndk other than the one kindle book called "ANDROID NDK" (lol).  That book I was able to understand but the whole setting up eclipse was confusing because it told me I need to set up cygwin, but then it told me I don't have to set up cygwin because of the ndk r7 supports the command line, so I was confused on the eclipse set up, and I've used eclipse for java but never for C++ where I had to convert my code to C++ in the project menu, So is there a better tutorial for the android ndk than that book.

if you guys can answer those two questions I would really appreciate it, and yes I know I probably should start with iOS rather than android, but I don't have a mac therefore I am not going to start with iOS, (correct me if I'm wrong here but!)) I figure if I can write android native C++ code, then the transition to iOS would not be that hard if I was to code in C++ on iOS with  Xcode 4.

Again books I should read tutorials I should go too would be extremely helpful thank you so much.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it doesn't really meet the requirements for a Stack Overflow question. First, you should ask 1 question per post, and second you should ask questions that have a definite answer. Personally, I think this one is good enough to let stand, but I point it out to help you (and the rest of us) get the most out of SO.  (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I apologize for the error that is my fault but thank you for letting it stand I'm just really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're still going to be building an iOS application. I don't understand how learning android C++ is going to help with iOS applications. You would still need a mac to compile and submit your application to the app store (at least you may need to borrow a mac to build and submit).

Also, I'm suggesting a different approach to your problem (aka not related to c++ solution but still may help you).

You can use phonegap (library that converts html, css, javascript to native iOS/Android/etc. applications). You simple code in html, css and javascript (also jquerymobile) and you can easily transfer your applications to different platforms.

Note: Phonegap's new name is Cordova.

You can find more info here: http://www.phonegap.com

Hope this helps!
-c0d3

Comment: I understand I need a mac for everything but truth is I'm only 21 and my boss doesn't think I'm capable for doing ios applications so if I can write a fully android application in c++ I'm hoping then he will buy me a mac to do ios applications (basically he doesn't want to invest in me before I can prove what I can do.... So that is why I need to prove it in android

Comment: I understand. If you use phonegap to develop your application in html, css, and javascript, it is very easy to transfer this application to iOS or other popular phone platforms including windows mobile. It's built to help developers save time. Once you build your application using phonegap, you include your html, css, javascript files in whatever platform you're developing for, hook up the phonegap plugin and it runs like a native app. Saves a lot of development time!

Comment: You can access phones (whatever phone it may be) native functionality such as Camera, GPS, etc through Phonegap javascript.

Comment: For phonegap is it good for like software development I won't be developing any games shouldn't be atleast.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/index.html This is what you can do with PhoneGap. No, its not for game development. Like I said, it's html, css, javascript. Those are not necessarily game development scripts/languages...

Comment: And also I don't know html css or javascript where can I start learning

Comment: Ouch, http://www.w3schools.com/ is probably a good place to look at. You can also watch tutorials on youtube. So, I guess you're finally coming to the light. PhoneGap is awesome!

Comment: Yeah im going to try it but I just showed my boss the link and everything he said we dont have any games yet but what happens when we do have games? am I screwed?

Comment: Yeah, PhoneGap isn't necessarily for game development. Sorry, I didn't know that was your ultimate goal. I'd stick with OpenGL and C++ then. However, when you switch to iOS, you'll have to pretty much re-write the game in Objective-C as far as I know. Though, I think you'll be able to copy paste most of your code to iOS since it is also C syntax. Hope this helps.

Comment: game development isnt in the books right now, so we might be using phonegap to bang out a few applications for now, but eventually the C++ or c is going to have to be the bottom line for any games we go to develop

Comment: I understand. Good luck! You can also watch lectures by Paul Hegarty in iTunes (iTunes university -> lectures by Stanford University) to learn iOS development in detail. The lectures are really good! I hope this helps. Thanks for voting up :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, how should I say this?

1) Books about C++: Have you tried the reference book?

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C/dp/0321543726/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334347108&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321543726)

You could get this one as well. It covers the basics and go through more practical usages of the language:

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C/dp/0321543726/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334347108&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321543726)

Herbert Shildt has a great book for C++:

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginners-Guide-Second-Edition/dp/0072232153/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334347407&sr=1-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072232153)

Bear in mind that all these books **do not cover** C++ new standard, C++0x (or C++11).

2) Since you're planning on multiplatform development, I would suggest using a mobile framework. Writing multiplatform C++ code for both systems (iOS and Android) is nontrivial. Also, iOS primary language is Objective C, which could be quite awkward looking for C++ (and even Java) developers BTW. 
Unfortunatelly, most mobile frameworks are web-based. If your application demands low level access, you might be out of luck.

Comment: Yeah, this is why I suggested phonegap. You can't do very low level stuff but you have access to a very good variety of functionality. They're also recently purchased by adobe and in active development. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to hide all platform specific code in a native library implementing a common interface. Your code will use the library only through the interfaces exposed, and the implementation is bound to the interface at compile-time by platform-specifics flags

I don't know of any android-iOS native cross platform development libraries, maybe there should be one?

Answer (score 0):

I swear by Marmalade.  I've used it for video game dev.  You can do entire ios dev, android dev, all from visual studio.

You will need itunes to deploy for ios, but that is about it.